# AreaChart Line Styling JavaFX

Tags: css, charts, javafx

Is it possible to change the Color of the Line in depency of the x coordinates?
So I need a Line with different colors, the colors must be set in depency of the x coordinate values... Thanks for your help.
[image]

I have nearly the same than this example. So now i want to change the color from X (Jan-March) / from April to Jun / Jul to Sep / Oct to Dec -> Is this possible? How can i do that with one line! Or is there a other solution?

Comment: Does JavaFX use markup to implement its graph? If so, where is your markup? If not, then CSS won't affect it.

Comment: Hello @TylerH what do you meaen with markup? English ist not my mother tongue, so I'm not so good in...

Comment: By markup, I mean HTML.

Comment: I have no idea about that fact! But i can change the colors and something like that... The problem is, that i have no idea if it is possible to change the color with step width ... @TylerH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to solve this problem. I have to make a lot of different series. So every Serie could be styled by itself. So it's only necessary to fit the end of one line (serie) to the startpoint of the next line (serie).

In this case it's very easy to style different colours for each line.